# Tkinter: cryptography.fernet decrypt returning blank string (b' ')

Tags: python, tkinter, cryptography

I am new to `tkinter` library. I have searched enough and debugged for hours but could not figure out why the decryption is not working. However, the code is working if used without `tkinter`.

Here is the code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key() # to make a key or to genrate a key
print(key)

from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

def clicked():
    input1 = ent1.get()
    FileName = str(input1)
    TextFile = open(FileName,"w")

    input2 = ent2.get()
    wrcont = str(input2)

    TextFile.write(wrcont)
    TextFile.close()

b1 = Button(root, text='SUBMIT',bg='light blue',fg='green',command=clicked)

b1.grid(row=2,sticky=E)

def encryption():
    print('In Encryption')
    input1 = ent1.get()
    FileName = str(input1)+".txt"
    TextFile = open(FileName,"w")
    with open(FileName,'rb') as TextFile:
        data = TextFile.read()
    fernet = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)
    decrypted = fernet.decrypt(encrypted)
    print(encrypted)
    print('Decrypted')
    print(decrypted)
    TextFile.close()
    print(key)
    with open(FileName, 'wb') as TextFile:
        TextFile.write(encrypted)
    TextFile.close()    
b2 = Button(root,text='ENCRYPT',bg='red',command=encryption)
b2.grid(row=4,column=2)

#for decryption

# open the file to decryption
def decryption():
    input1 = ent1.get()
    file = str(input1)+".txt"
    #TextFile = open(file)
    print('In Decryption')
    print(file)
    with open(file,'rb') as TextFile:
        token = TextFile.read()
    TextFile.close() 
    print(token)
    #print(data)
    print(key)
    fernet = Fernet(key)
    decrypted = fernet.decrypt(token)
    print('decrypted data')
    print(decrypted)
# write the encrypted file
    file = file+"dec"
    with open(file, 'wb') as TextFile:
        TextFile.write(decrypted)
    TextFile.close()     
b3 = Button(root,text='DECRYPT',bg='red',command=decryption)
b3.grid(row=5,column=2)


l4 = Label(root,text='Enter file Name to Decrypt:',bg='light blue')
ent4 = Entry(root)

l4.grid(row=5,sticky=S)
ent4.grid(row=5,column=1)


l1 = Label(root, text='Enter your file name:',bg='light blue')
l2 = Label(root, text='Write some text into file:',bg='light blue')

ent1 = Entry(root)
ent2 = Entry(root)

l1.grid(row=0,sticky=E)
l2.grid(row=1,sticky=E)

ent1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=E)
ent2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=E)

l3 = Label(root, text='Enter file to encrypt:',bg='light blue')
ent3 = Entry(root)

l3.grid(row=4,sticky=E)
ent3.grid(row=4,column=1)


root.title('FILE ENC/DEC')
root.geometry('800x500')
root.configure(background='purple')
root.mainloop()
```

**Output (console)**:

```
b'QsQpCVnYOIQcdG-JjAwi_sw3Qqc7fB6eyeQ8zf9oPs4='
In Encryption
b'gAAAAABcrtxDIgMvDsYAV6GzpVVE3UYLZtwArC07E8johAQgOTbLUwjCJab1A4UnniZbtJOJiepRHcX04xKnCcdbpFktTHsqcQ=='
Decrypted
b''
b'QsQpCVnYOIQcdG-JjAwi_sw3Qqc7fB6eyeQ8zf9oPs4='
In Decryption
aaa.txt
b'gAAAAABcrtxDIgMvDsYAV6GzpVVE3UYLZtwArC07E8johAQgOTbLUwjCJab1A4UnniZbtJOJiepRHcX04xKnCcdbpFktTHsqcQ=='
b'QsQpCVnYOIQcdG-JjAwi_sw3Qqc7fB6eyeQ8zf9oPs4='
decrypted data
b''
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `TextFile = open(FileName,"w")` in your encryption function is incorrect and is causing this bug. When you open a file for writing with `w` it is immediately truncated so all the contents are lost. The next line then re-opens it in binary read mode, but it will just read an empty byte string at that point. Your fernet instance then encrypts the empty byte string and upon decryption you (correctly) see nothing.